# How to show a RSS feed button for aggregator node page

Tags: feeds

I use the Aggregator module to display RSS contents. I want to have a RSS button along with the aggregator node, how can I enable or add the button to page?

Answer (score 1):

The RSS icon should already appear automatically on the page. If not, check your theme's `page.tpl.php` file and make sure it has this line on it:

```
<?php print $feed_icons ?>
```